Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' (17)
I have tried all of the listed solutions I can find on the Internet and am stumped.
I'm updating to Java 17 from 1.8, and I am getting the error:
Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' (17).

I have changed all of the recommended options
I have Invalidated Caches and Restarted Multiple Times
I have Cleaned the project many many times
Each of the above was done after each one of the following changes

Module build.gradle:
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }

    tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = '17'
        }
    }

App level build.gradle
     tasks.withType(KotlinCompile).configureEach {
        kotlinOptions {
            jvmTarget = "17"
            freeCompilerArgs += [
                    "-P",
                  "plugin:androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin:suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck=1.9.0",
                    "-Xjvm-default=all",
            ]
        }
    }
...
     kapt {
        arguments {
            arg("room.schemaLocation", "$projectDir/schemas")
            arg("kapt.jvmTarget", "17")
     }
}

Project level build.gradle:
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools:r8:8.3.37'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.2.2'
...

build.gradle.kts:
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.9.24"
}
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

val compileKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}

val compileTestKotlin: KotlinCompile by tasks
compileTestKotlin.kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}

gradle.properties:
// Commented out top line to switch to the bottom to prevent daemon errors
#org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx14g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m

// Added this line
org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home 

gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.4-rc-1-bin.zip

Added line to ~/.zshrc:
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 17)

Gradle Settings:

Project Structure:


I have changed all of the recommended options
I have Invalidated Caches and Restarted Multiple Times
I have Cleaned the project many many times
I have removed all of the Java 8 JDKs
Each of the above was done after each one of the following changes

The project will not build because of the error:
Inconsistent JVM-target compatibility detected for tasks 'compileDebugJavaWithJavac' (1.8) and 'kaptGenerateStubsDebugKotlin' (17).
